# PHP - Check if tinyint has (1) in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I already know how could I UPDATE this values, but I am a litle confused about how can I get this current values.

**So, here's my code:**

```
    <?php
            //READ DB
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT ativo FROM Spot", $db);

            if(!$result){
                die("ERRO" . mysql_error());
            } else {

            //RETURN RESULT
            while ($result != '1') {
                echo '<div>IT'S TRUE</div>';
                }
                echo '<div>IT'S FALSE</div>';
            }

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the current value of a field in database?

Comment: You need to go away and do some basic learning on how to do sql queries in php.

Comment: @Dave, why? I said that I am able to UPDATE, but I am just confused of how could I get "TRUE" or "FALSE" value.

Comment: @SandeepNayak yes, I do.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fetch the result from that query. Like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ativo FROM Spot", $db);

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if ($result['ativo'] == 1) {

 // is 1

} else {
  // not 1
}
```

Comment: This works very well, thanks. But this is not showing the right value. I tested and `echo '1';`. So far so good... After doing `UPDATE 'Spot' SET 'ativo'=0 WHERE 1` its echo same result.

Comment: should be UPDATE Spot SET (ativo = 0) WHERE ativo = 1

Comment: I guess not. `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ativo = 0) WHERE ativo = 1' at line 1` :(

Comment: Sorry my mistake. should be UPDATE Spot SET ativo = 0 WHERE ativo = 1

Comment: or if ativo is string: UPDATE Spot SET ativo = "0" WHERE ativo = "1"

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `mysql_query()` is actually an resource identifier and not the data, you request. To get the actual data, you have to fetch it first, e.g., by using [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT ativo FROM Spot", $db);

        if(!$result){
            die("ERRO" . mysql_error());
        } else {

        //RETURN RESULT

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           if( $row['ativo'] != 1 ) {
             echo '<div>IT\'S TRUE</div>';
           } else {
             echo '<div>IT\'S FALSE</div>';
           }
        }
```

<sup>I also corrected the missing escaping of `'` inside your string. See the highlighting in your question, what went wrong there.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

first you have to use other quotes

not

```
echo '<div>IT'S TRUE</div>';
```

should be like

```
echo "<div>IT'S TRUE</div>";
```

second

your query returns a resoure id, so it never will be 1 ^^

```
<?php
        //READ DB
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT ativo FROM Spot", $db);

        if(!$result)
        {
            die("ERRO" . mysql_error());
        } 
        else 
        {

            //RETURN RESULT
            while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                echo $data['ativo'] . "<br/>";
            }
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//RETURN RESULT
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['ativo'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        //READ DB
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT ativo FROM Spot", $db);

        if(!$result){
            die("ERRO" . mysql_error());
        } else {

        //RETURN RESULT
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $value = $row['ativo'];
            if($value!=1){
              echo '<div>IT\'S TRUE</div>';  // escape special chars
            }
            else{
              echo '<div>IT\'S FALSE</div>';  // escape special chars
            }
        }

?>
```